# How to pass 2 different data from a child component into the v-model of a parent component?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I'm using vuejs 2 and typescript in a project. I would like to pass two different data inside the parent component. `data` and `attachments` using vue-property-decorator. I don't know how to reference `attachments` when I'm already using data in the Parent component `v-model` ? Do you know the proper way to do it ?

### Parent Component

```js
<template>
  <ChildComponent 
  v-model="data" 
  :attachments="attachments" How to refer attachments ?
  />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'
import ChildComponent from '~/components/ChildComponent'

@Component({
  components: {
    ChildComponent
  }
})
export default class ParentComponent extends Vue {
  data: any = {};
  attachments: any = [];
}
</script>
```

#### Child Component

```js
<template>
  <form>
    <input type="text" v-model="data.firstname" />
    <input type="text" v-model="data.lastname" />
    <input type="file" multiple v-model="attachments" />
  </form>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, VModel, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'

@Component
export default class ChildComponent extends Vue {
  @VModel() data!: any;
  @VModel() attachments!: any;
}
</script>
```

Thank you for your support and your help.

Comment: How about using attatchments as `data.attachments` in the Child Component? Then emit `input` event whenever data gets changed.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in Vue3 SFC, sorry for no TS - should be easy to convert though.

Props to ChatGpt.

Parent with v-model:

```
<template>
  <ChildComponent v-model="parentData" />
  <p>Parent Data: {{ parentData }}</p>
</template>

<script setup>
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent.vue';
import { ref } from 'vue';

const parentData = ref('');

</script>
```

Child with a watcher and emits (not my favorite):

```
<template>
  <input v-model="modelValue" />
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, watch, emit } from 'vue';

props: {
  modelValue: {
    type: Object,
    required: true
  }
},

const childData = ref('');

// Update the childData with the prop value
childData.value = props.modelValue;

// Watch for changes in childData and emit them to the parent component
watch(childData, (newValue) => {
  emit('update:modelValue', newValue);
});
</script>
```

I can probably be optimized more, but calling it a day.

The emit with 'update:x' syntax is new to me as I was hoping to just bind all the objects together, but no luck.

Hopefully, someone can provide a more elegant solution.